# Mutual notification patterns

Tags: .net, design-patterns

Propose to consider the following problem.

Suppose we have some composite object. 
Are there patterns that describe the solution of mutual notification of composite object parts, when states of these parts are changed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the [Mediator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) pattern from the original [Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612) book.

Answer (score 0):

[EN]May be, *EventBus*, where all parts of object publish their events and subscribe.

[RUS]Может попробовать *EventBus*, где части объекта публикуют свои события и подписываются на события других частей